# Count unique values of actual year (not present in previous years)

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and I was hoping you can help me with a question. I have a table from which I need to count unique values of this year, if they do not exist in years before (Basically I want to know only new entries for 2016).

```
BP Name       Year
A             2013
B             2016
A             2014
A             2016
C             2012
C             2016
```

In this case it would count only as 1 (BP Name: B)

Thanks
Kastriot

Comment: Which DBMS/Server you are using?

Comment: I am using Zoho Reports (not sure if this helps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

"unique values this year" =Table Name
BP Name and Year = Columns

```
 select t."BP Name", t."Year" from 
(select "BP Name", "Year" from "unique values this year" where year("Year")=2016) t  
left join (select "BP Name" from "unique values this year" where year("Year")!=2016 ) t1 on t."BP Name"=t1."BP Name" 
    where t1."BP Name" is null
```

Comment: Thanks Titus, this worked great.

My final query for other people who might need this (please note that table and column names are different from what I posted here):

`SELECT DISTINCT t."BP Name"
FROM ( SELECT
    "BP Name",
    "Disbursment Date"
 FROM  "SB_MD" 
 WHERE  year("Disbursment Date")  = Year(getdate())
) t LEFT JOIN( SELECT "BP Name"
 FROM  "SB_MD" 
 WHERE  year("Disbursment Date")  < year(getdate())
) t1 ON t."BP Name"  = t1."BP Name"  
WHERE  t1."BP Name"  is null`

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this with two levels of aggregation.  The following does the count for all years:

```
select first_year, count(*)
from (select pbname, min(year) as first_year
      from t
      group by pbname
     ) t
group by first_year;
```

For just 2016:

```
select count(*)
from (select pbname, min(year) as first_year
      from t
      group by pbname
     ) t
where first_year = 2016;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select count(*)
from
(select Distinct bpname,year
 from tmpBP a 
where a.year=2016 
and not exists  (select 1 from tmpBP b where a.bpname = b.bpname and a.year > b.year
)
)x
```

Answer (score 0):

check with this.

```
select count(*) from table1 a 
where a.year=2016 
and not exists  (select 1 from table1 b where a.bpname = b.bpname and a.year > b.year)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(BPName),BPName,_Year FROM #Temp otr WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #Temp inr WHERE inr.BPName = otr.BPName and inr._Year > otr._Year ) GROUP BY BPName,_Year
```